# Reverse Proxy Kubernetes routing to external-cluster application

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-load-balancer

We have a load-balancer in kubernetes, and it works perfectly with ingress to route traffic to our pods, using subdomains.
We are splitting our site to be on an external host, and keeping most of it in our website pod in kubernetes.
We want to keep the same subdomain but split it based on url routes.
Eg:
web.omer.com is the dns now,
we want web.omer.com/dashboard to point to our kubernetes pod (easy through ingress)
and web.omer.com/sign-up to point to external app hosted with FQDN outside of our kubernetes cluster: omer.webflow.com.

Tried using the external-service, which works ok but it redirects the url, causing the url to redirect from web.omer.com/sign-up to omer.webflow.com, while we wish to keep our dns. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our LoadBalancers do support [Internet Network Endpoint Group](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/internet-neg-concepts).

The main challenge is that you cannot configure that via Ingress. The Ingress API doesn't have a way to mention an FQDN as a backend to a specific host/path.

You will not be able to edit the existing Loadbalancer to add an internet NEG because the Ingress controller will revert your changes.

The only way i can think of this is to use [Standalone NEG](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/standalone-neg) using Terraform or something like that